# While binding `this` to onClick event on React component is giving `Parameter 'this' implicitly has an 'any' type` error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

P.S. I've tried the other answer from StackOverflow but somehow that did not work.

I'm binding `this` to the onClick function handler as given below

```
  const handleUpdatePermissionClick = async (user: UserPermission) => {
    try {
      await updateUserPermission(user)
      setShowError(false)
    } catch (e) {
      setShowError(true)
    }
  }

  <MenuItem
    name={ele.name}
    Key={ele.name}
    onClick={handleUpdatePermissionClick.bind(this, { permission: ele, userId })}
  />
```

But it gives me `Parameter 'this' implicitly has an 'any' type` error`.

I tried assigning multiple types viz. any, void,typeof to `this` as

```
onClick={handleUpdatePermissionClick.bind(this:any, { permission: ele, userId })}
```

But it gives type not required error. Please help me out with the issue.

Comment: Can you share the screen shot also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following change is what worked for me. Instead of bind I just passed normal event.

While calling onClick handler function used `React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>` as event type

And in function definition used '_e' to suppress the `param defined but not used` error.
Adding it here so that it might help someone in the future.

```
const handleUpdatePermissionClick = async (_e:React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>,user: UserPermission) => {
   try {
      await updateUserPermission(user)
      setShowError(false)
   } catch (e) {
      setShowError(true)
   }
}

 <MenuItem
   name={ele.name}
   key={ele.name}
   onClick={(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
     handleUpdatePermissionClick(e, { permission: ele, userId })
   }}
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to the context.
in render before return just do as following;
let that = this;
and call the function using that instead of this.
It worked for me.